# How to sort different outputs in prolog according to their lengths?

Tags: list, prolog, size, predicate

How can I sort/display all different outputs that make a predicate true according to their list size?

for example, if the output before is:

```
X = [1,2,3,5,5,2,1,4,1]

X = [1,2,3,1]

X = [1,2,1,3,1,3]
```

What can I do so that it outputs like this:

```
X = [1,2,3,1]

X = [1,2,1,3,1,3]

X = [1,2,3,5,5,2,1,4,1]
```

Comment: You can either collect all solutions and sort them in some way, or, you can change the predicate that delivers these solutions to find them in the order you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your procedure always returns a list, you can collect all solutions, sort them according to the list length and then iterate over the sorted list.

E.g., assume you have a procedure `something(L)` which returns a list, you can do this:

```
sorted_something(L):-
  findall(Len-L, (something(L), length(L, Len)), AllL),
  keysort(AllL, SortedAllL),
  member(_-L, SortedAllL).
```

The call to `findall/3` will collect all solutions and their lengths, `keysort/2` will sort the solutions according to their length, and `member/2` obtains each list from the sorted list of solutions.

Comment: What about removing duplicate solutions? What can I write in the code that would exclude duplicates from being displayed in the solutions?

Comment: @Swailem95 Look up the three predicates for collecting solutions: `findall/3`, `bagof/3`, and `setof/3`.

Answer (score 0):

sort and duplicates removal can be performed by setof/3:

```
:- meta_predicate(sorted_lists(1,?)).

sorted_lists(Generate_a_list, SortedByLenght):-
  setof(Len-L, (call(Generate_a_list, L), length(L, Len)), All),
  member(_-SortedByLenght, All).
```